# how to pass a new component for a link text in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I would like to have a text in react component and one word in this text as a link that will lead to another webiste?

My component looks like this:

```
import { oneOf, string } from "prop-types"
import * as Styled from "./Banner.styled"

const Banner = ({ variant, size, text }) => (
  <Styled.Banner variant={variant} size={size}>
    {text}
  </Styled.Banner>
)

Banner.propTypes = {
  text: string.isRequired,
  variant: oneOf(["complementary", "complementary", "complementary"]),
  size: oneOf(["complementary", "complementary", "complementary"]),
}

Banner.defaultProps = {
  variant: "complementary",
  size: "medium",
}

export default Banner
```

I am using storybook to show with the component and styled.js to style them,  but my question is, could you please hep me how should I pass to this componett a link?

My text should go like that:

I am learning react, please click this (link) That should be a link to another website.

could you please help me with creating component for  a link?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the normal  tag for a link in react too. And then just pass a ReactElement (`PropTypes.element`) as text (instead of type string), e.g.:

```
<Banner
   text={<>I am learning react, please click this <a href="URL">link</a></>}
   variant={..}
   size={...}
/>
```

Note: The <> and </> tags are used to wrap the two Nodes (text and `<a>`) into one "container", it won't generate a new HTML element in the DOM.

You will also need to change your proptype:

```
text: oneOf([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.element]).isRequired,
```

Comment: Note he also probably needs to change the proptype for this to not throw a warning